# Move key-specified element to the front of an associative array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array with string indices, that I need partially sorted. That is, some elements must be moved first, but the others should remain untouched in their current (PHP-internal) order:

```
# The element with key "c" should be first
$foo = array(
    "a" => 1,
    "b" => 2,
    "c" => 3,
    "d" => 4,
);

uksort($foo, function ($a, $b) {
    if ($a === "c") {
        return -1;
    } elseif ($b === "c") {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
});

var_dump($foo);
```

What I expected:

```
array(4) { ["c"]=> int(3) ["a"]=> int(1) ["b"]=> int(2) ["d"]=> int(4) }
//--------------------------^ "a" remains first of the unsorted ones
```

What I got:

```
array(4) { ["c"]=> int(3) ["d"]=> int(4) ["b"]=> int(2) ["a"]=> int(1) }
//--------------------------^ "d" moved above "a"
```

This seems due to the sorting algorithm `uksort()` uses internally, which destroys the fragile order of elements. Is there any other way to achieve this sorting?

Comment: What part of the array do you actually need sorted?

Comment: I need an array, that, when put in a `foreach` loop, provides the keys in the order "c", "a", "b", "d". I have an array, that has the keys such, that the order is  "a", "b", "c", "d". From that I need to get to the above one.

Comment: I meant what's the logic? You want to move the specific element to the top? You want to move the 3rd element to the top? What do you want when the array is of different length?

Comment: Actually, I want elements with the key "c" to be placed first. Use case is a special CSS serialization. I need keys named "@charset" to be first, keys named "@import" to be second, and all others (arbitrarily many) should remain in their position.

Comment: Maybe I'm not interpreting this correctly, but you could have at most one "@charset" key and one "@import" key, so you'll be moving 2 elements at the most?

Comment: Yes, exactly. That's what this special format looks like unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **any** `sort` function is overkill for this task.  You merely need to merge the input array into a lone array containing the element which should come first.  The array union operator (`+`) will do nicely for your associative array (otherwise `array_merge()` will do).

Codes: ([Demos](https://3v4l.org/r92vS))

if key c is guaranteed to exist:

```
$foo = array(
    "a" => 1,
    "b" => 2,
    "c" => 3,
    "d" => 4,
);
$foo = ['c' => $foo['c']] + $foo;
var_export($foo);
```

if key c might not exist check for it first:

```
$bar = array(
    "a" => 1,
    "b" => 2,
    "d" => 4,
);
if (array_key_exists('c', $bar)) {
    $bar = ['c' => $bar['c']] + $bar;
}
var_export($bar);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'c' => 3,
  'a' => 1,
  'b' => 2,
  'd' => 4,
)
```

and

```
array (
  'a' => 1,
  'b' => 2,
  'd' => 4,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me and returned:

`array(4) { ["c"]=> int(3) ["a"]=> int(1) ["b"]=> int(2) ["d"]=> int(4) }`

```
<?php 

# The element with key "c" should be first
$foo = array(
    "a" => 1,
    "b" => 2,
    "c" => 3,
    "d" => 4,
);

uksort($foo, function ($a, $b) {
    if ($a === "c") {
        return -1;
    } else
        return 1;
});

var_dump($foo);

?>
```